# ListView not being populated

Tags: android

In my DATABASEADAPTER CLASS, I have written the following code:

```
public Cursor getdetails(){
          Cursor mCursor = db.query(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID,
                  CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME, CONTACTS_COLUMN_PASSWROD, CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL, CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE,CONTACTS_COLUMN_ADDRESS}, 
            null, null, null, null, null);
         return mCursor; 
     }
```

In my List activity I have done the following:

```
public class List extends Activity {
     private LoginDataBaseAdapter database;
     Cursor cursor;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            database = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
            database.open();
           cursor = database.getdetails();
           ListView lst = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
           @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(
             this,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
             cursor,
             new String[] {cursor.getColumnName(cursor.getColumnIndex("CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME"))},
             new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
          lst.setAdapter(adapter);
    database.close();
     }
        }
```

Comment: 1. did you check that this line:cursor = database.getdetails(); returns something other than null? 2. you should use cursor loader callbacks, as getting something from the database can take some time, and you may need to call "lst.notifyDataSetChanged()" before you see any result

Comment: you might be missing the `_id` column for the cursor adapter

Comment: I suspect closing the database makes it no longer possible to read the contents of the cursor.